# Spring boot app with Jython on raspberry pi

Tags: java, spring-boot, raspberry-pi, jython

i am trying to use jython in my Spring boot project on raspberry pi. I have a problem because it's work when i run it on windows, but doesn't work on raspberry pi(system raspbian). It's crashing on new PythonInterpreter().

Code:

```
try {
        PythonInterpreter pyInterp = new PythonInterpreter();
        pyInterp.exec("print('Hello Python World!')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

ImportError: Cannot import site module and its dependencies: No module named site
Determine if the following attributes are correct:

- sys.path: [/home/pi/Dysk/raspdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/Lib, **classpath**, **pyclasspath**/]
  This attribute might be including the wrong directories, such as from CPython
- sys.prefix: /home/pi/Dysk/raspdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib
  This attribute is set by the system property python.home, although it can
  be often automatically determined by the location of the Jython jar file

You can use the -S option or python.import.site=false to not import the site module

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, that might help

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i resolved the problem. I had to initiate that properties, and the props.put("python.import.site", "false"); parameter to run was important.

```
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("python.home", "/home/pi/Dysk/jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar");
        props.put("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
        props.put("python.security.respectJavaAccessibility", "false");
        props.put("python.import.site", "false");
        Properties preprops = System.getProperties();
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(preprops, props, new String[0]);

        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("print('Hello Python World!')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```